# Is it true that MongoDB has one global read/write lock?

Tags: mongodb, locking

I am reading this article - http://wiki.postgresql.org/images/7/7f/Adam-lowry-postgresopen2011.pdf and I noticed that an ugly part of mongoDB is the global lock.
Is it true that MongoDB has a global lock for read/write operations? what about the latest versions? Is there a plan to change that?

Comment: This is not a properly constructed question. You should be more specific, and maybe include the relevant portions of the link you included.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a per-database lock. So if you are writing to multiple databases, as I am in one project, you can write concurrently to them all.

Answer (score 13):

yes. it's true:  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work

but they are working on it, if you look at the change log of the 2.0, they started to deal with it:  http://blog.mongodb.org/post/10126837729/mongodb-2-0-released

The read/write lock is currently global, but [collection-level locking is coming soon](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1240)

Comment: Global lock is gone in Mongodb 2.2 http://blog.serverdensity.com/goodbye-global-lock-mongodb-2-0-vs-2-2/

Comment: @Brian - But we still have DB level locking, which for many people is the same thing.

Comment: in mongo 2.4 there implemented other ways to yield the DB level locking in some case and the direction (probably 2.6 or later) is to have collection level locking.

Comment: Coming soon eh? It has been over 2 years and the collection-level locking issue is Open, Unresolved, and unassigned...sigh.

Comment: yeah, that's a shame, but at least we got db level locking...

Comment: @BrianArmstrong it is resolved in 2.7.8